# Programa "pulando" Variáveis

Tags: c, variáveis

O programa está pulando as variáveis sem ao menos eu colocar o número que eu quero usar nele. Só consigo colocar o primeiro e depois pula e resulta em zero.
Não sei se e erro do programa **Dev-C++** ou do código.

---

[image: Erro]

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
    float basemaior, basemenor, altura, resultado;
    printf ("entre com a base maior do trapezio: ");
    scanf ("f%", &basemaior);
    printf ("entre com a base menor do trapezio: ");
    scanf ("f%", &basemenor);
    printf ("entre com a altura do trapezio: ");
    resultado=(basemaior+basemenor)*altura / 2;
    printf ("\no calculo da area de um trapezio e: f%", resultado);
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Sugiro que ligues os warnings do teu compilador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código possui 3 erros:

1. Ao invés de `void main()`, use `int main()`. **Alguns** compiladores podem não aceitar a primeira forma. Então é recomendável usar `int main()`, sendo o `int` o retorna do seu programa, indicando que o programa foi executado com sucesso, por exemplo.
2. Onde está `f%`, o correto é `%f`.
3. Está faltando um `scanf()` para a altura.

Fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float basemaior, basemenor, altura, resultado;
    printf ("entre com a base maior do trapezio: ");
    scanf ("%f", &basemaior);
    printf ("entre com a base menor do trapezio: ");
    scanf ("%f", &basemenor);
    printf ("entre com a altura do trapezio: ");
    scanf ("%f", &altura);
    resultado=(basemaior+basemenor)*altura / 2;
    printf ("\no calculo da area de um trapezio e: %f\n", resultado);
    system ("pause");

    return 0; // por causo do int main
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você trocou o especificador de formato de posição.

Ao invés de `f%`, troque-os por `%f`.

Além disso, para que o cálculo seja feito corretamente, adicione um scanf para a altura:

```
scanf ("%f", &altura);
```